# Gradle 3.5.1 error error: cannot find symbol someclass.java

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle

Hi while building gradle project using Jenkins I'm getting below error
error: cannot find symbol someclass.java

Locally it is working fine but in Jenkin server showing java build error.

Answer (score -1):

update your gradle to the latest version.